# Complex sub-query in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables
 1 attend_master contains

```
AM_ID Attend_Date Time_From Time_To Course_ID Subject_ID
 1     2014-03-10  10:00     11:00    1        22
 2     2014-03-10  10:00     11:00    1        23
```

2nd Attend_Child

```
CA_ID   AM_ID   Roll_No  Attendance
1           1       1         1
2           1       2         0
3           1       3         1
4           2       1         1
```

I want result like this

```
Subject_ID    Total_Absenty   Total_Lectures
22             2                10
23             5                11
```

I have tried

```
select AM.Subject_ID, count(AC.Attendance) as Attendance
,
(
    select count(AC1.Attendance) from Attend_Child AC1
    inner join Attend_Master AM1 on AC1.TT_ID = AM1.TT_ID
    where AC1.Roll_No = 3 AND AM1.Course_ID = 1 AND DATENAME(Month, AM1.Attend_Date) = 'March'
)
 from Attend_Child AC
inner join Attend_Master AM on AC.TT_ID = AM.TT_ID
where AC.Roll_No = 3 AND AM.Course_ID = 1 AND AC.Attendance = 0 AND DATENAME(Month, AM.Attend_Date) = 'March'
group by AM.Subject_ID, AM.subject_Type
```

by using this i am getting incorrect result.
how can i use group by in subquery?

Comment: Seems to me like you're omitting some fields in your table...

Comment: Can I ask where the complex sub query is? I mean, I am used to queries 2-3 pages long.... this is not complex at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CourseID INT =1
DECLARE @Month varchar(10)='March'

SELECT m.SubjectID
    ,Count(*) [Lectures] --count of all classes attended or not
    ,Count(*)-SUM(c.Attendance) [Absences]--count of all - attended classes
FROM Attend_Master m
INNER JOIN Attend_Child c
    ON m.AM_ID=c.AM_ID  --WHAT IS TT_ID?
WHERE m.CourseID=@CourseID
    DATENAME(Month, m.Attend_Date) = @Month
    --AC.Roll_No = 3  --WHAT DOES THIS DO FOR YOU?
GROUP BY M.Subject_ID
--, AM.subject_Type  --WHERE DID THIS COME FROM?
```

Comment: Hi Daniel E. Thanks for reply 1. TT_ID is by mistake its AM_ID 2. AC.Roll_No is for particular student's Enrollment no. if i want to see result of particular student. 3. No need of AM.subject_Type.

Comment: you can always add `Roll_ID` to the `select` and the `group by` to get individual results...

Comment: I am passing Roll_ID through keyboard. I want result of selected student only.

Comment: Gotcha, consider adding a variable for Roll_ID as well then, and you can wrap this all into a stored procedure.